# Monitoring Android activity life-cycle callbacks

Tags: android

I want to be able to launch an arbitrary app from a program (e.g. by executing the command "am start ", then have the program be notified in some way when the life-cycle callbacks (e.g. onStart, onStop) in the app's activity are called.

The problem is that I can not rely on having the app's source code, so can not modify it to add code to the app's implementations of those callbacks.

Is there any way to do this without modifying the Android activity manager, or writing a custom activity manager?

Answer (score 1):

The regular activity manager can give you the name of the running task (getRunningTasks), but I'm afraid there is no interface you can implement to get callbacks when a task is started/stopped.

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid of that.  It looks like I'm going to have to modify the activity manager itself.

Comment: Looking at the doc, I just saw this interface : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html But it feels like these callbacks are just for activities within your app :/

Comment: Yes - and I can't alter the source code of the app.  I have been looking at ActivityThread, and I think I can probably add code to this to broadcast an intent when it calls the onStart or onStop callbacks in the app. Then the monitoring program can receive the intents and do whatever is required.  Fortunately this is for internal use, since it means building and installing Android on the target device.